# Inserting table data in to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Just going crazy on what's wrong here.

all I am trying to do is : ***"Take two columns from one table and insert in to other table"***

[image]

The query that I use is this:

```
insert into Component_Capacitor values (Component_Capacitor.itemNo, Component_Capacitor.itemDescription)
  select [Item No#], [Item Description] from dbo.Sheet1$ where 
  [Item Description] LIKE 'CAP %' ;
```

The error is this:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Component_Capacitor.itemNo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Component_Capacitor.itemDescription" could not be bound.
```

I checked the syntax, table-name and everything seems to be fine.

The column types are also similar `(nvarchar(255),null)`

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Remove the word `values` from your insert statement.

Comment: @Marc: Exact. Worked like a charm. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use SQL Server, but I think you need to remove the word "values" from your statement.

```
insert into Component_Capacitor (Component_Capacitor.itemNo, Component_Capacitor.itemDescription)
  select [Item No#], [Item Description] from dbo.Sheet1$ where 
  [Item Description] LIKE 'CAP %' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into Component_Capacitor 
(Component_Capacitor.itemNo, Component_Capacitor.itemDescription)
  select [Item No#], [Item Description] from dbo.Sheet1$ where 
  [Item Description] LIKE 'CAP %' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace column names & table names properly. This should work.

```
INSERT INTO DBO.COMPONENT_CAPACITOR (ITEMNO, ITEMDESCRIPTION)
SELECT A.ITEMNO, A. ITEMDESCRIPTION FROM SHEET A
WHERE ITEMDESCRIPTION LIKE 'CAP%'
```

Comment: The error you got actually due to, the format should be like,     insert into destination_table (col1, col2,...) select (S.col1, S.col2,...) from source_table S

Answer (score 0):

use `ItemNo` for the  `Item No` and same things in `Item Description` simple remove the White space. 
and remove values name in code

Comment: user3044294, its not the answer & it will not work. You have to use [] instead. Spaces can not be removed.

Comment: Yes but the source table has col names with spaces so how can you remove spaces & then try ?